# Why Am I unable to dynamically update my CSS values using variable in reactjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So, I am trying to update the CSS values using CSS variables. It's my first time of trying to do this though.
No error seen, the previous value remained, didn't change. Here are my codes:

CSS variable declaration

```
:root {
--tx: -0%;
}

.move{ 
 transform: translateX(var(--tx));
}
```

In my react, I created a `useState` and provided a `-33` value to it for testing

```
 const [movePosition, setMovePosition] = useState(-33);
```

I created a function to handle to check if the CSS variable would be updated using the value provided in the `movePosition` state

```
const handleNextSlide = ()=>{
  setSlider1(slider1 + 1);
  setSlider2(slider2 + 1);
  setSlider3(slider3 + 1);
 getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--tx', 
 `${movePosition}%`);
 }
```

I created a button to handle the `onClick` event that calls the function above

```
 <MdNavigateNext onClick={handleNextSlide}/>
```

When clicked, the CSS values does not change to the `movePosition` state value which is `-33`. I even hard coded it, it still didn't change. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

In reactjs you you can update CSS variables by wrapping it in a string

```
<MdNavigateNext onClick={handleNextSlide} style={{'--tx':`${movePosition}%`}}/>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. But it didn't update

Comment: oops sorry, i set the wrong variable i edited it

Answer (score 0):

The right API to update CSS variables is:

```js
const handleNextSlide = ()=>{
  setSlider1(slider1 + 1);
  setSlider2(slider2 + 1);
  setSlider3(slider3 + 1);
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--tx', `${movePosition}%`);
}
```

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed the .setProperty and I have learnt that from you today. Thank you very much.